# Issues to show point cloud density using javascript API

Tags: javascript, api, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

I have a  sample which shows how to change size and density of points in a PointCloudLayer. Each PointCloudLayer renderer has two properties: **pointSizeAlgorithm** and **pointsPerInch**. One can change the point size and the other can change the point density.

For me , the point size is working fine, but I am facing issues with point density, whatever I select on my bar, it didn’t reflect in the map.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <title>
      PointCloudLayer - change point size and density | Sample | ArcGIS API for
      JavaScript 4.21
    </title>
    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }

      #paneDiv {
        width: 270px;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 14px;
      }

      .title {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .slider {
        margin: 20px 0;
        height: 40px;
        width: 95%;
      }
    </style>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.21/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.21/"></script>

    <script>
      require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/SceneView",
        "esri/layers/PointCloudLayer",
        "esri/widgets/Slider"
      ], (Map, SceneView, PointCloudLayer, Slider) => {
        // create slider for point size
        const selectedPointsSize = 5;
        const pointsizeSlider = new Slider({
          container: "point-size-slider",
          min: 1,
          max: 15,
          values: [selectedPointsSize],
          steps: 0.5,
          snapOnClickEnabled: false,
          visibleElements: {
            labels: true,
            rangeLabels: true
          }
        });
        // watch for changes on the sliders and update the renderer according to the new values
        pointsizeSlider.on(
          ["thumb-change", "thumb-drag"],
          pointsizeValueChanged
        );
        function pointsizeValueChanged(event) {
          const newRenderer = pcLayer.renderer.clone();
          newRenderer.pointSizeAlgorithm.size = event.value;
          pcLayer.renderer = newRenderer;
        }

        // create slider for point size
        const selectedPointsPerInch = 5;
        const pointsperinchSlider = new Slider({
          container: "points-per-inch-slider",
          min: 1,
          max: 40,
          values: [selectedPointsPerInch],
          steps: 1,
          snapOnClickEnabled: false,
          visibleElements: {
            labels: true,
            rangeLabels: true
          }
        });
        // watch for changes on the sliders and update the renderer according to the new values
        pointsperinchSlider.on(
          ["thumb-change", "thumb-drag"],
          pointsperinchValueChanged
        );
        

        // create map and view
        const map = new Map({
          basemap: "gray-vector",
          ground: "world-elevation"
        });

        const view = new SceneView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map,
          camera: {
            heading: 210,
            tilt: 78,
            position: {
              x: -8249335,
              y: 4832005,
              z: 50.7,
              spatialReference: {
                wkid: 3857
              }
            }
          }
        });

        // create Point Cloud Layer with a renderer with set values for point size and point density
        const pcLayer = new PointCloudLayer({
          url: "https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/BARNEGAT_BAY_LiDAR_UTM/SceneServer",
          renderer: {
            type: "point-cloud-rgb", // autocasts as new pointCloudRGBRenderer()
            field: "RGB",
            pointSizeAlgorithm: {
              type: "fixed-size",
              useRealWorldSymbolSizes: false,
              size: 5
            },
            pointsPerInch: 5
          }
        });

        // add layer to the map
        map.add(pcLayer);
        // add panel to the map
        view.ui.add(document.getElementById("paneDiv"), "bottom-left");
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
    <div id="paneDiv" class="esri-widget">
      <div class="title">Customize point cloud layer:</div>
      <div>Point size:</div>
      <div id="point-size-slider" class="slider"></div>
      <div>Points per inch:</div>
      <div id="points-per-inch-slider" class="slider"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the handler function `pointsperinchValueChanged` of `pointsperinchSlider` for `thumb-change` and `thumb-drag` events.

```
pointsperinchSlider.on(
    ["thumb-change", "thumb-drag"],
    pointsperinchValueChanged // <- you did not define the function
);
```

Here is the definition of the example [ArcGIS JS Examples - PointCloudDensity](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-pointcloud-size-density/),

```
function pointsperinchValueChanged(event) {
    const newRenderer = pcLayer.renderer.clone();
    newRenderer.pointsPerInch = event.value;
    pcLayer.renderer = newRenderer;
}
```

Just add it to your code and it will work.